# APK lost 30% of filesize

Tags: android, eclipse

I changed to W8 - Installed Eclipse x64 and imported my Workspace. After running the app I saw that the .apk file lost about ~30% of the filesize. Now Im a little  but confused. I checked all my project-files but it seems fine.

Can anybody tell me how this happend? Maybe new Java/Eclipse Version? Auto cleanup task?

Thanks

Comment: Did you activate proguard... it has that effect

Comment: its activated, but I grab my apk from the `bin` folder so proguard souldnt modify anything?

Comment: I noticed that my classes.dex changed from 750kb to 150kb..

Comment: proguard is activated in release mode and required file are packaged as .apk. So the size should reduce. I recently read a answer to similar question. After update the .apk reduces was what the post said. May be google now has higher compression ratio . Hence the reduce size of .apk. You should not worry about it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems that this is a really new feature becouse the eclipse version I used before was not old